# RDLC export to excel convert to number error

Tags: rdlc

I am exporting RDLC to excel, the price and quantity columns are displaying warning as "The number in this cell is formatted as text". I have set tablix Price textbox to "Currency", quantity to "Number". But still exported as text.

So we are supposed to change each cell to "Convert to Number" in excel.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, set this to Number from textbox properties. Then set an expression something like this: **=CInt(Sum(Fields!YourPropertyName.Value))**

Answer (score 0):

you can try 
FormatNumber(FieldName,2 ,,TriState.True,TriState.True) In RDLC Expression.